# Find the index value of a character stored in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I'm looking out to print the index value of a respective character as many times as it would appear `using HashMap`.

For example, let's say I have `String str = "Hello World"`. The program as of now displays the occurence of characters via `{d=1, W=1, e=1, r=1, o=2, l=3, H=1}`.

What I intend to achieve as resultset is `{d=[9], o=[4, 6], r=[7], W=[5], H=[0], l=[2, 3, 8], e=[1]}` where `*=[*]` represents `key=[indexValue]`.

(The whitespace character is not to be taken into consideration in the final resultSet.)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ConcordanceOfStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello World";

        //code to remove whitespaces        
        String newStr = str.replaceAll(" ", "");

        Map<Character, Integer> numCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(Math.min(newStr.length(), 26));

        System.out.println("The count is: ");
        for(int i=0; i<newStr.length(); i++){
                char charAt = newStr.charAt(i); 
                if(!numCount.containsKey(charAt)){  
                    numCount.put(charAt, 1);    
                }
                else{
                    numCount.put(charAt, numCount.get(charAt)+1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(numCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then a `Map<Character, Integer>` is not enough, you'd need a `Map<Character, Set<Integer>>`, so that you can store each index while iterating the string. Mind that if you don't use a SortedSet they won't be in order.

Comment: @Jack - Any specific reason for a Set<Integer> to be applied ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. Right now, you are storing the result in a `Map<Character, Integer>`, so a map from each character to the number of times it appears in the String.

To store all the indexes where the character appears, you need to have a `Map<Character, List<Integer>>`: each character will be mapped to a list of integers, which will be the list of the indexes where this character appears.

In your current code, you just need to adapt the logic that populates the map:

```
if(!numCount.containsKey(charAt)){  
    numCount.put(charAt, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i))); // <-- we store a list containing the first index i
    // numCount.put(charAt, 1);
} else{
    numCount.get(charAt).add(i); // <-- we add to the existing list the index i
    // numCount.put(charAt, numCount.get(charAt)+1);
}
```

In the case where the map doesn't contain the character, we initialize the mapping with a list containing the first index `i`. `Arrays.asList(i)` returns a fixed-size list so I wrapped it in another `ArrayList`.

In the case where the map already contains the character, we just need to get the current list of indexes and add the one we just found.

---

If you are using Java 8, your whole code could be written more simply with Streams:

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> numCount = 
    IntStream.range(0, str.length())
             .filter(i -> str.charAt(i) != ' ')
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 i -> str.charAt(i),
                 Collectors.mapping(v -> v - 1, Collectors.toList())
             ));
```

Comment: I didn't quite catch the reason behind initializing the ArrayList, when you are storing the resultSet in HashMap.  #JustAsking

Comment: @mindfreak I edited to add more explanation. You have to initialize the mapping with something since at first there is no mapping.

Comment: Awesome explanation. But I guess the syntax in the code represents Java 8, which at this moment I'm not familiar with. But anyways, you did a remarkable job. Thanks once again !!

Comment: @mindfreak Not all of it. The first part of the code isn't specific to Java 8 :). I only provided another solution to show how it could be done using the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

You need something more than just Map you need something like Map>. Here is a example of a modification to your algorithm:

```
    Map<Character, List<Integer>> positions = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Character, Integer> numCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(Math.min(newStr.length(), 26));

    for (int i = 0; i < newStr.length(); i++) {

        char charAt = newStr.charAt(i);
        if (!numCount.containsKey(charAt)) {
            numCount.put(charAt, 1);
        }
        else {
            numCount.put(charAt, numCount.get(charAt) + 1);
        }

        if(!positions.containsKey(charAt)){
            List<Integer> cPosition = new LinkedList<>();
            cPosition.add(i);
            positions.put(charAt, cPosition);
        }
        else{
            List<Integer> cPosition = positions.get(charAt);
            cPosition.add(i);
            //positions.put(charAt, cPosition); because of references there is no need to do this
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are replacing the list with itself in the map? Sure you could optimize it.

Comment: @MrinalK.Samanta You are right because of references that line can be removed. Thanks for the suggestion.